Would solving the Liar's Paradox allow for self-meta-logics?
By self-meta-logic, I mean a logic that is its own meta-logic; a logic that can talk abouts its models.
If I understand correctly, this is impossible (for "interesting" logics at least) due to Tarski's Undefinability Theorem. Any "interesting" logic will derive this theorem, which means that if that logic contains a truth predicate, it would be inconsistent (and thus no longer "interesting").
But Tarski's theorem relies on a sentence structurally identical to the Liar's Paradox (ie. this sentence is false). Some people talk of solving this paradox, somehow. One can imagine different kind of solutions. Like, one can solve it in the sense of protecting one's logic from inconsistency introduced by the Liar's Paradox, by for example making it not a wff. I imagine that kind of solution might not be relevant to my question. A solution where one can somehow, free of contradiction, assign a truth-value to the Liar's Paradox however, does seem quite relevant to my question.
If a solution was ever found for the Liar's Paradox, would it allow for interesting self-meta-logics? Perhaps even revive Hilbert's Program?
(Let me know if this question is better suited to Philosophy.SE)

I do think that the question is better suited for philosophy.se. For what it's worth (I'm no philosopher), logics can be also "not interesting" because they are in some sense "too weak", even if they are not (we don't know that they are) inconsistent. But philosophical logicians do study such weaker logics, with some kind of restricted truth predicate (usually, disallowing self-reference, or paraconsistent, or something of the sort), and the theory is quite rich as far as I know, but I don't think there is any real hope for revival of Hilbert's program.

It seems to me that the Liar Paradox is not so much a problem in logic as it is one in linguistics where sentences can be true, or false or of indeterminate truth value. Examples of the latter include all questions and instructions, as well as "This sentence is false." See my posting at https://www.dcproof.com/LiarParadoxResolution.htm This analysis requires only bivalent logic and some very basic set theory.
